# How to mask "hr" line with rounded div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need something look like this:

[image]

I have used the bootstrap framework. The line "hr" should not visible behind the circle div (as shown in the picture). Is it possible with css masking??

My code is below:

```css
.container.bg {
  background: url(https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-silhouettes-of-colleagues-discussing-business-issue-in-dark-office-377738314.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
  }
.about-info {
 padding-top:70px;
 padding-bottom:90px;
 position:relative
}
.about-info hr {
 position:absolute;
 width: 100%;
    right: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    top: 40%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.about-info .text {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:rgba(153,153,153,0.5);
 border-radius:100%;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:14;
 margin:0 auto
}
.about-info .text span {
 display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
 font-family:helverticacb;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:20px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container bg">
<div class="row about-info">
<hr>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><div class="text pull-left"><span>Honesty</span></div></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center"><div class="text"><span>Transparency</span></div></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><div class="text pull-right"><span>Integrity</span></div></div>
</div>
  </div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what masking is, but do it with z-index

Comment: I would suggest your to use separate `hr` lines..

Comment: @DaniSpringer i have tried.. but its not working

Comment: @GuruprasadRao could you add a fiddle please...

Comment: you can give hr a z-index 0 but your .text element opacity will cause the line to still show. Do you want it with 0.5 opacity only?

Comment: @Deep Yes.. need the transparency for .text element

Comment: Note: should be two hr elements, so no need to go behind the circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

you may want to tweak it some (note: that the flex widths and height may scale on differently on viewports of different sizes

```css
.container.bg{
  font-size:5em;  
}
.flex-container {
  min-height:5em;
  background: url(https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-silhouettes-of-colleagues-discussing-business-issue-in-dark-office-377738314.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  /*makes the container a flex-box*/
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  /* centers the stuff V*/
}
.hr {
  flex-grow: 2;
  /* make the rules 2x the width as circles*/
  height: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.text {
  font-family: impact;
  font-size: .3em;
}
.about-info {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
  /*position: relative*/
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container bg">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="about-info">
      <div class="text "><span>Honesty</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hr"></div>
    <div class="about-info">
      <div class="text "><span>Transparency</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hr"></div>
    <div class="about-info">
      <div class="text "><span>Integrity</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great effort... but i think it is not compatible with IE (flex), also circle isn't exact shape  :(

Comment: how can i shape the circle?

Answer (score 1):

(3 edits)

It's the opacity that prevents z-index from "working".
Note: z-index is doing its job, but if the top layer is transparent, you'll see under it.

```css
.container.bg {
  background: url(https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-silhouettes-of-colleagues-discussing-business-issue-in-dark-office-377738314.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
  }
.about-info {
 padding-top:70px;
 padding-bottom:90px;
 position:relative
}
.about-info hr {
 position:absolute;
 width: 100%;
    right: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    top: 40%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.about-info .text {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:rgba(153,153,153,1);
 border-radius:100%;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:14;
 margin:0 auto
}
.about-info .text span {
 display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
 font-family:helverticacb;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:20px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container bg">
<div class="row about-info">
<hr>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><div class="text pull-left"><span>Honesty</span></div></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center"><div class="text"><span>Transparency</span></div></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><div class="text pull-right"><span>Integrity</span></div></div>
</div>
  </div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT #2:**
Perhaps you can make the hr's opacity the same?

```css
.container.bg {
  background: url(https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-silhouettes-of-colleagues-discussing-business-issue-in-dark-office-377738314.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
  }
.about-info {
 padding-top:70px;
 padding-bottom:90px;
 position:relative
}
.about-info hr {
 position:absolute;
 width: 100%;
    right: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    top: 40%;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: rgba(153,153,153,0.1);
    color: rgba(153,153,153,0.1);
    height: 5px;
}
.about-info .text {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:rgba(153,153,153,0.9);
 border-radius:100%;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:14;
 margin:0 auto
}
.about-info .text span {
 display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
 font-family:helverticacb;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:20px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container bg">
<div class="row about-info">
<hr>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><div class="text pull-left"><span>Honesty</span></div></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center"><div class="text"><span>Transparency</span></div></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><div class="text pull-right"><span>Integrity</span></div></div>
</div>
  </div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT #3:** use 2 `<hr>` instead of 1.

```css
.container.bg {
  background: url(https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-silhouettes-of-colleagues-discussing-business-issue-in-dark-office-377738314.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
  }
.about-info {
 padding-top:70px;
 padding-bottom:90px;
 position:relative
}
hr {
 position:absolute;
 width: auto;
    right: 5px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 30px;
    color: red;
    background-color: red;
    color: red;
    height: 2px;
    border: 0;

}
.text {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:rgba(153,153,153,0.9);
 border-radius:100%;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:14;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.text span {
 display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
 font-family:helverticacb;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:20px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container bg">
  <div class="row about-info">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
      <div class="text pull-left">
        <span>lorem</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="text text-center">
        <span>lorem</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
       <div class="text pull-right">
         <span>lorem</span>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No transparency... No need to use my element / classes.. any other ways are acceptable... but result should look like as in the picture

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `:after` on `.text`? so something like:

```
.text:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 115px;
    display: block;
    width: 210px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

And from there adjusat the width/height etc to get it looking it proper.

Take a look at the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mjwtL2ze/3/

Comment: nice.. but its not working perfectly in all window width